# Multi Site Error Messages in M2

Tags: magento-2.1, error

Does anyone know how to specify pub/errors themes per store rather than using the same template for all stores?

I have created my theme in pub/errors using the local.xml but I am unsure of the next steps.

Thanks in advanced!